# strange problem in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a little server app with Java. So, I'm getting informations from different client, and if information comes in, the following method is called:

```
public void writeToArray(String data) {
    data = trim(data);
    String[] netInput = new String[5];
    netInput[0]="a";
    netInput[1]="a";
    netInput[2]="a";
    netInput[3]="a";
    netInput[4]="a";
    netInput = split(data, ",");
    pos_arr = PApplet.parseInt(netInput[0]);
    rohr_value = PApplet.parseInt(netInput[1]); // THIS LINE KICKS OUT THE ERROR.
    if(pos_arr >0 && pos_arr<100) {
        fernrohre[pos_arr] = rohr_value;
        println("pos arr length: " + fernrohre[pos_arr]);
        println("pos arr: " + pos_arr);
    }
```

The console on OS X gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1
 at server_app.writeToArray(server_app.java:108) at server_app.draw(server_app.java:97)
 at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1606)
 at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1503)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

As you can see, I tried to fill the array netInput with at least 5 entries, so there can't be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I don't understand that, and I'm thankful for your help!

It would work already for me, if I can catch the error and keep the app continuing.

Comment: Please provide the code of the `split` method

Comment: @Carlos I read that as `data.split(",");` good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some defensive code,

```
if(netInput.length > 1)
   pos_arr = PApplet.parseInt(netInput[0]);
   rohr_value = PApplet.parseInt(netInput[1]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, maybe this is already enough, because it's working for an uncertain time, and maybe one time, he doesn't get the comma, and then it crashes. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You put 5 Strings into the array, but then undo all your good work with this line;

```
netInput = split(data, ",");
```

`data` obviously doesn't have any commas in it.

Comment: +1 to What @carlos said. Almost all of us here assumed that `split` works as expected.

Comment: I think the fundamental misunderstanding here is the array re-initialization even if the problem itself exists in the split-method or not. The way that the array is incorrectly "pre-initialized" with five strings really to me points out that it's not expected for the split to return enough values.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The `split()` method is custom, not `String.split`. It too needs to be checked to see what is going wrong. Thanks [@Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85421/carlos-heuberger) for pointing it out.

**Original Answer**

Consider this line:

```
netInput = split(data, ",");
```

This will split the `data` string using comma as a separator. It will return an array of (number of commas + 1) resulting elements. If your string has no commas, you'll get a single element array.

Apparently your input string doesn't have **any** commas. This will result in a single element array (first element aka index = 0 will be the string itself). Consequently when you try to index the 2nd element (index = 1) it raises an exception.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I send:
 c.write(FERNROHR_ID + "," +target +"\n"); 

So data has a "," in it. I want the first part, BEFORE the comma is netInput[0], and the second part, AFTER the comma is in netInput[1]. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: @nbuechi: you need to double check the data. Try printing it to sysout and see what turns up. You logic for splitting is correct, but apparently the data is not showing up in the way want.

Comment: please note that the code is NOT (directly) calling `String.split()`!

Comment: @Carlos: Thanks dude. That was a good catch. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
netInput = split(data, ",");
```

your array is being reinitialized. Your `split` method probably returns an array with only 1 element (I can guess that data string doesn't contain any ",").

Answer (score 1):

You make 
 `netInput = split(data, ",")`;
and
split(data, ",");

```
returns one element array
```

Comment: What I do, when I send is: 
c.write(FERNROHR_ID + "," +target +"\n");

So data has a "," in it. I want the first part, BEFORE the comma is netInput[0], and the second part, AFTER the comma is in netInput[1]. 

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: then I can assume that FERNROHR_ID - is an empty string.

Comment: Or target  is an empty string

Answer (score 1):

You are re-assigning your `netInput` variable when the `split()` method is called.

The new value might not have an array count of 5.

Can you provide the source for the `split()` method?

Comment: I assume the split() method is part of the class/super-class where the writeToArray() method is called. Since String is final and cannot be extended.